# SQL Server: Serial number generator implementation question

Tags: sql, sql-server

My clients need a format of serial #: YYYYMMDD098 where **YYYYMMDD** represents today, **098** is a 3-digit number that will get increased by 1 every time we access the serial #.

Furthermore, the 3-digit # will **trun back to zero** every day.

Where can I find a reference for this solution?

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to add the specific database you're using (oracle, mysql, etc.).  The solution will probably be somewhat database dependent.

Comment: Hi tschaible, thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server

```
DECLARE @OldID char(11), @NewID char(11);
DECLARE @IDbit char(3), @CurrDate char(8)

SET @OldID = '20091027098'
--SET @OldID = '20091026098'

SELECT
    @IDbit = SUBSTRING(@OldID, 9, 3),
    @CurrDate = CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 112)

IF @CurrDate <> LEFT(@OldID, 8)
    SET @NewID = @CurrDate + '000'
ELSE
    SET @NewID = @CurrDate + RIGHT('00' + CAST(CAST(@IDbit AS tinyint) + 1 AS varchar(3)), 3)

SELECT @NewID
```

Comment: and preferably wrap that into a TRANSACTION so no two competing requests will happen to get the same ID

Comment: @marc-s: no table or resource to lock though. However, as a udf for a key column, possibly...

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need a table for storing those serial numbers. Make sure you store the date and the number in separate columns, so that you can manipulate them easily. To generate a new serial number then do (in a transaction):

- Lock the table to avoid a race condition when trying to generate two serial numbers at the same time. How to do this depends on the database you are using, but you want a lock that allows reads, but disallows writes.
- `SELECT max(serial_no) FROM table WHERE serial_date = ?`.
- If the result is `NULL`, make it 0, otherwise increment it by one.
- Insert the new serial number to the table.
- Unlock the table.

Answer (score 0):

That seems too much of a specific requirement for there to be an off-the-shelf solution somebody can just point you to. I'm not too clear what you mean by 'access' because you have to have an update of some kind to remember where you've got to so far. Also, I'd use more than a 3 digit counter - you're bound to overflow that some time.

I'd suggest something along these lines:

Set up a table with one row to hold the counter and set its initial value to today's date + 000 (eg. 20091027000). Create a stored procedure that, inside a transaction, increments the counter and returns the new value. To restart the sequence at 000 each morning you could either do this in a scheduled job or get the stored procedure to compare the date part of the counter with today's date and reset the counter if it's not today.

Comment: Hi, by access, I meant retrieving that counter value :)